# No http version found in request header in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http

When I inspect my site in Google Chrome, I didn't find the http version(1.1 or 2.0) in request header, Did I miss any settings?

[image]

This is want I wonder to see(**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an optian, right click on response column, and select protocal.

[image]

and h2 means http2 here.

[image]